# Cleaning user inputs in FuelPHP

Tags: security, sql-injection, fuelphp

I am quite new to the FuelPHP framework. Right now I'm implementing an "autocomplete" for a list of locations.

My code looks like this:

```
public function action_search($term=null){
    $clean_query =  Security::clean($term);
    $data["locations"] = array();
    if ($clean_query != "") {
        $data["locations"] = Model_Orm_Location::query()
                             ->where("title", "like", $clean_query."%")
                             ->get();
    }

    $response = Response::forge(View::forge("location/search", $data));
    $response->set_header("Content-Type","application/json");
    return $response;
}
```

As you can see, I'm concatenating a `LIKE` statement and it sort of feels bad to me. Is this code safe against SQL injections ? If yes, then is it because:

- `Security::clean` will remove all mess;
- `where()` in the ORM query will do the filtering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [implementation of `Security::clean` in the source code of *core/class/security.php*](https://github.com/fuel/core/blob/1.5/develop/classes/security.php#L92), in your case the applied filters depend the [configuration *security.input_filter*, which is empty by default](https://github.com/fuel/core/blob/1.5/develop/config/config.php#L142). So no filter is applied.

But when you dig deep into the database abstraction, you will see, that when the query is [compiled](https://github.com/fuel/core/blob/1.5/develop/classes/database/query.php#L188) just before execution, the [query builder will apply `quote` on the value](https://github.com/fuel/core/blob/1.5/develop/classes/database/query/builder.php#L126) that was supplied in the *where* condition, [which will then apply `escape` on string values](https://github.com/fuel/core/blob/1.5/develop/classes/database/connection.php#L442). The implementations of that `escape` method depend on the DBMS connection:

- [`mysql_real_escape_string` for *mysql*](https://github.com/fuel/core/blob/1.5/develop/classes/database/mysql/connection.php#L424),
- [`mysqli::real_escape_string` for *mysqli*](https://github.com/fuel/core/blob/1.5/develop/classes/database/mysqli/connection.php#L441), and
- [`PDO::quote` for PDO](https://github.com/fuel/core/blob/1.5/develop/classes/database/pdo/connection.php#L318).

This reflects today’s best practices. So, yes, this is safe against SQL injections.

Comment: A great answer! Thank you for digging that deep into the framework!